# malloc a struct in kernel header file error :invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm new to linux.
I'm practice syscall and I want to copy struct to user.

So I write a syscall which is using copy_to_user().

But When I write and compile test.c to test my syscall appear some error.

in linux/sched.h has defined:

```
struct pacct_struct {
    int ac_flag;
    long ac_exitcode;
    unsigned long ac_mem;
    cputime_t ac_utime, ac_stime;
    unsigned long ac_minflt, ac_majflt;
};
```

and then I write a program that use this struct(test.c)

```
#include "linux/sched.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    struct pacct_struct *ts;
    ts = (struct pacct_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct pacct_struct));
    return 0;
}
```

and gcc show the follow error message:

```
test.c:6:44: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct pacct_struct'
```

I wonder to know if it's fine to use kernel struct by include header file. 
If so, do I miss something? How to make pacct_struct become a 'complete type'?

thanks.

**addition**:

I check preprocessor with gcc -E

I found that seems no "struct pacct_struct" being included.

Next, I going to view sched.h that I included which was created by "make headers_install" after I compile the kernel.

The file only contains some cloning flags such like "#define CSIGNAL 0x000000ff"

So, I tried to include original source file of sched.h in dir "/usr/src/linux-2.6.39.4/include/linux", but it continue showing same error 'incomplete type'.

Then I check preprocessor again.

I still can't find 'struct pacct_struct' even I include original header file

Anything in sched.h after `#ifdef __KERNEL__` is disappear, What happened?

Comment: @PSkocik I use kernel version 2.6.39.4. In this version it appears in `include/linux/sched.h`

Comment: Is `cputime_t` defined in linux/sched.h?

Comment: It means that the definition of `struct pacct_struct` is not visible.  Where are you seeing it?  Is it perhaps defined in a conditional compilation block?

Comment: @okovko : If it were not but `pacct_struct` were visible, you'd get a different error I think.  The sched.h being included is most likely lacks this definition.

Comment: @Clifford [sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/include/linux/sched.h)
It seems not defined in a conditional aompilation block

Comment: @Clifford sched.h may declare but not define `cputime_t`, in which case you'd get an incomplete type error.

Comment: @Okovko cputime_t defined in asm/cputime.h as typedef u64 cputime_t

Comment: @CedricVincent try adding `#include "linux/types.h"`

Comment: @okovko same error occur

Comment: Okay, this one's just a hunch: try `malloc(sizeof(*ts))`. You're able to declare `struct pacct_struct`, but it's erroring on the `sizeof`. Let's see if the compiler can determine the size through the `*ts` deref of a variable you've declared, whose declaration the compiler was happy with.

Comment: @okovko error changed : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182696/discussion-between-okovko-and-cedric-vincent).